# draw outline for some connected lines

Tags: vb.net, computational-geometry, autocad, outline

I have some lines that are connected at various points. I want to draw the outline of these lines and I also want to deal with the extra lines at the connection points.

I have seen two similar questions in this website: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687173/how-do-i-render-thick-2d-lines-as-polygons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641769/how-to-draw-an-outline-around-any-line)

I have handled the normal cases by offsetting the Centerlines and then changing the start and end points of the lines.

but I haven't been able to deal with special cases when the points are near each other.

Unfortunately, my reputation is low I couldn't post images to explain this better.

I'm coding in Visual Basic .net and I'm writing for Autocad, but any advice will be very useful to me.

Comment: look at my answer ... btw there is a big difference if you are doing outline on the outside of the shape or to the inside ... (inside needs much much more checking for original line crossing and more ... single question thread is not enough for that topic more like a title for entire book if I had the mood and time for it ...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

most problem cases are solved by translation vectors intersection check

[image: outline]

- black is the original line/curve whatever ...
- gray is translation vector (normal to black and size = outline distance)
- blue is outline

if the translation vectors not intersect then it is most likely all OK but if they do then just do something like this:

1. cut off these points from outline
2. or create some singular point from these intersections

   it is more tricky but can avoid some problem cases from bullet #1

Also sometimes help if there is bigger density of control points

Hope it helps a little...