# How to subdivide irregular polygons in SVG

Tags: svg, graphics, computational-geometry

Given a polygon of indeterminate shape, and given you know which path(s) to start from, I need to slice up these polygons (defined in SVG format) into n shapes using the start-path as a guide.

It's kind of hard to explain, but think seat sections and their rows in a stadium:
[image: sections cut into rows]

When dealing with rectangles, it doesn't seem too difficult. What I'm stuck on is how to do it with an irregularly shaped polygon. A universal solution would be best, especially if it can work with curves but I can see how that would only complicate matters.

Is there any specific algorithm that I should start my studies with? I've started digging into polygon triangulation and how to use ear clipping methods to decompose these polygons in a monotone fashion, but my head is starting to spin here.

PS: Not sure if it's super important, but these polygons are defined in SVG.

Comment: What are the paths and their starting points for the two example polygons?  Will the polygons always be symmetric?

Comment: Symmetry: no.
Our metadata will hold onto which side(s) of the polygon determine the "front row" so we know what the starting point is.

Comment: Is the top path a scaled version of the bottom start path? If not, the problem is more challenging.

Comment: see [polygon spiral filling](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31013424/2521214) it is similar problem. just create stroke line with `i*w` distance from the leading path polyline and then construct the polygons. `w` is the layer thickness and `i=0,1,2,3,...`

Comment: Do you want your path to be always the same, moved in steps. Or do you want your path to shrink/increase depending on the slope of its lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very naive approach: simply interpolating between top and bottom vertices (that are sorted left to right) based on how many division/'rows' you need.

I've done a quick test using [Processing](http://processing.org):

```
PShape svg,shape;

int divisions = 3;

ArrayList<PVector> top = new ArrayList<PVector>();
ArrayList<PVector> bottom = new ArrayList<PVector>();

int numVerts;
int ptSize = 5;

void setup(){
  svg = loadShape("shape.svg");
  size((int)svg.width,(int)svg.height);
  shape = svg.getChild(0);
  //find top and bottom vertices
  numVerts = shape.getVertexCount();
  float minY = height,maxY = 0;
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numVerts; i++){
    PVector v = shape.getVertex(i);
    if(v.x < minY) minY = v.y;
    if(v.y > maxY) maxY = v.y;
  } 
  float yThresh = (maxY-minY) * .25;//1/4 of height as top/bottom thresh
  //store vertices belonging to top and bottom based on min and max y values and threshold
  for(int i = 0 ; i < numVerts; i++){
    PVector v = shape.getVertex(i);
    if(v.y <= minY+yThresh) top.add(v);
    if(v.y >= maxY-yThresh) bottom.add(v);
  }
  //manual left to right sorting, this needs to be implemented properly
  PVector last = bottom.get(bottom.size()-1);
  PVector first = bottom.get(0);
  bottom.set(0,last);
  bottom.set(bottom.size()-1,first);
  //assumptions is top is a list of the top vertices of the contour sorted left to right
  //and simillary bottom is a list of bottom vertices, sorted left to right
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  shape(shape,0,0);
  //visualize top/bottom vertices
  stroke(0,192,0);
  for(PVector v : top) ellipse(v.x,v.y,ptSize,ptSize);
  stroke(192,0,0);
  for(PVector v : bottom) ellipse(v.x,v.y,ptSize,ptSize);
  stroke(0,0,255);

  //compute interpolation step value
  float lerpStep = 1.0/(divisions+1);

  //for each division
  for(int i = 0 ; i < divisions; i++){

    //loop through contour vertices top to bottom
    for(int j = 0 ; j < top.size(); j++){
      //get top and bottom vertices
      PVector vTop = top.get(j);
      PVector vBottom = bottom.get(j);
      //interpolate between them
      PVector vLerp = PVector.lerp(vTop,vBottom, lerpStep * (i+1));
      //draw on screen
      ellipse(vLerp.x,vLerp.y,ptSize,ptSize);
    }

  }
}

void keyPressed(){
  if(keyCode == UP) divisions++;
  if(keyCode == DOWN) divisions--;
}
```

And here is shape.svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="960px" height="560px" viewBox="0 0 960 560" enable-background="new 0 0 960 560" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon fill="#D8D8D8" points="279,100 479,60 681,100 641,501 480,482 322,501 "/>
</svg>
```

Here is a preview, with top vertices marked green, bottom red and interpolated vertices as blue:

[image: SVG vertex interpolation]

As @Joseph O'Rourke mentions, the problem is more challenging if the bottom and bottom paths aren't similar (same number of vertices and left to right order I guess). 
In this case it should be possible to implement a blending algorithm (like [this one](http://students.byu.edu/~tom/papers/arc.pdf) for example). If you're already playing with various shape in SVG format, you should be able to test if blending solves your problem by trying it in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/doc/interpolate/tutorial-interpolate.en.html) or Illustrator beforehand.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. I now have everything I need to get moving on a full-fledged solution.

Comment: Glad that helps! Keep in mind the limitations I've mentioned: my naive approach always assumes a top and bottom path with equal number of vertices.