# how to calculate anti/clockwise angle in direction of lines?

Tags: python-3.x, math, geometry

I need to offset a curve, which by the simplest way is just shifting the points perpendicularly. I can access each point to calculate angle of each line along given path, for now I use atan2. Then I take those two angle and make average of it. It returns the shortest angle, not what I need in this case.

- How can I calculate angle of each connection? Concerning that I am not interested in the shortest angle but the one that would create parallel offset curve.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 2D case...

So do a cross product of direction vectors of 2 neighboring lines the sign of z coordinate of the result will tell you if the lines are CW/CCW

So if you got 3 consequent control points on the polyline: `p0,p1,p2` then:

```
d1 = p1-p0
d2 = p2-p1
```

if you use some 3D vector math then convert them to 3D by setting:

```
d1.z=0;
d2.z=0;
```

now compute 3D cross:

```
n = cross(d1,d2)
```

which returns vector perpendicular to both vectors of size equals to the area of quad (parallelogram) constructed with `d1,d2` as base vectors. The direction (from the 2 possible) is determined by the winding rule of the `p0,p1,p2` so inspecting `z` of the result is enough.

**The `n.x,n.y` are not needed so you can compute directly without doing full cross product:**

```
n.z=(d1.x*d2.y)-(d1.y*d2.x)
if (n.z>0) case1
if (n.z<0) case2
```

if the `case1` is CW or CCW depends on your coordinate system properties (left/right handness). This approach is very commonly used in CG fur back face culling of polygons ...

if `n.z` is zero it means that your vectors/lines are either parallel or at lest one of them is zero.

I think these might interest you:

- [draw outline for some connected lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068534/2521214)
- [How can I create an internal spiral for a polygon?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31013424/2521214)

Also in 2D you do not need atan2 to get perpendicular vector... You can do instead this:

```
u = (x,y)
v = (-y,x)
w = (x,-y)
```

so `u` is any 2D vector and `v,w` are the 2 possible perpendicular vectors to `u` in 2D. they are the result of:

```
cross((x,y,0),(0,0,1))
cross((0,0,1),(x,y,0))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't know how but I manage to do it following your instructions. finding out whether angle is CW or CWW was very handful enough. I couldn't really understand what follows after the links. Can you explain it, please? What is u, v, w and what are x, y.. x, y of which point?

Comment: @Jansindl3r `u` is any 2D vector (direction) defined by `x,y` ...  `v,w` are 2 possible perpendicular vectors to `u` one is `u` rotated in `CW` direction and the other in `CCW` ... so to compute perpendicular vector in 2D you just swap `x,y` and negate one of them no need to do `atan2` and then `cos,sin` ...