# Follow wall algorithm (with constant distance)

Tags: algorithm, behavior, curve, robotics

I am sure I've seen algorithm about what I want but I can not put my hands on it when I browse the web.

So what I am looking for is an algorithm that makes my robot follow a wall, keeping at all times the same distance (when possible).
Only the part about the positionning on the side of the wall.

A bit like this, except here the distance is not constant:

[image: Convex corner]

[image: Concave corner]

[image: Curve]

Thank you for the help!

Extra:
Here is a picture of my issue when following the wall step by step with constant distance to it: (blue is the robot position and red is the normal to the wall)
[image]

Comment: see [draw outline for some connected lines](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17021885/2521214) so convert your spatial/cognitive map to set of polylines and shift by distance towards the robot position ... then plan its path along this shifted line

Comment: you can also use modified A* which account for robot size for motion planning. I am sure I was answering one question about this but I cant find it now (may be deleted or just cant find the right search words)

Comment: Thank you. My problem is more like the "outline" post you refer to. I don't want my robot to go back on the track (when the normals cross). I add an image to show my problem.

Comment: what is the problem exactly?  you do not know how: 1. to detect intersection (line vs. line)?  2. remove intersecting parts (delete/skip from set)? 3. shift the wall polyline toward robot (rotate line direction by 90 degree and shift control points by it)? 4. handle some special case ?

Comment: This is the "offset curve" problem, which is a tough problem to tackle with, especially when the offset distance is not a constant. You might want to search "offset curve" in Google to get more references.

Comment: @Spektre Sorry for the delay, I am working hard on this and I didn't have much time to look here. So my problem is to move my robot following the normal of the wall at a specific distance. The robot move by step and at every step I look for the next target. But how we can see on the last image some of the normal cross each other. Making the robot go back for few steps. I want to detect when the next step will cross futur steps and I want to avoid using those step. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @fang Thank you for the term, I didn't know it, I will look about it now.

Comment: @Silouane so you do not know the whole map prior to motion planing? in that case before each step scan if you are near corner and if yes change direction

Comment: Hi did you approach this? I have a similar problem and I would love to share it with you so you might help me.