# Calculate approximate outline from polygon points

Tags: math, polygon, concave

I have a series of points that make up a polygon (the green dots below), these are connected with straight lines to make the polygon (the blue lines). I want to calculate the red lines, I've tried a few approaches around scaling the points and the lines but they always ended up with intersecting red lines which I don't want.

The green dots/blue lines polygon is drawn by the user so it could be any non-intersecting polygon.

Is it possible to calculate the red line, even approximately?

(If the red line had to go into the channel on the top of the polygon that would fine)

[image]

Comment: Look for `Alpha shape`

Comment: see [draw outline for some connected lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068534/2521214) if the gap is smaller than the outline distance then its skipped ...