# How to calculate curve line perpendicular offset?

Tags: c++, math

I have a set of  positions of a curve line which red line of image,
Now I have to calculate positions of rest curve lines which green line of image.

I want to combine all lines as polygon for draw which the  blue line of image, I can't use line with to do it. Because I need to render color by measure data.

Now I draw blue line with triangles.

How should I calculate perpendicular curve line offset?

[image: image 1]
[image: Image of Line Channel Description]

Comment: In fact I tried dx,  still incorrect,   Maybe I should not use slope of line to render multiple curve line.

Comment: all channels data I have to render as curve line. And I need to combine all channel data as one curve line to render on the screen.  It like width of line.   but I only get one set of positions for channel 1.  I tried to calculate  perpendicular  curve line of channel 1 curve line for other channels, but seems doesn't work well.

Comment: Please have another go at explaining what (geometrically) you are trying to do. The description at the moment is incomprehensible, and the linked image is no help. I suspect that there is a language barrier here.

Comment: Thank you for support, I close the question, and re-post by clear description

Comment: Can you demonstrate what kind of offset you want, with an actual curve, not a line? How is your curve defined, by a list of points? Is there any non-linear interpolation?

Comment: I have a set of offset values of  other channels.  like below,  Yes I have  a list of points of base curve line,  No I don't have any non-linear interpolation.  

X_OFFSETS:0.6835 0.5535 0.4235 0.2935 0.1635 0.03350002 -0.09649998 -0.2265 -0.3565 -0.4865 -0.6165 
Y_OFFSETS:0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998 0.002499998

Comment: In fact, the  list of points are gps location, and channels offset values are transmitter and receiver  offset of gps device .

Comment: Well, your Y_OFFSETS are all the same and the X_OFFSETS are (equi-spaced) along a line. But I'm still completely at a loss to understand what you are trying to do. What exactly do you mean by "curve line" and "perpendicular curve line offset"? Do you have some reference link (preferably in English) to explain this?

Comment: I just add another image(Image of Line Channel Description) to describe my question.
Every line is channel,  I just would like to render this polygon with color mapping.  but I only got a list of points of first line,   I calculated  the points of rest of lines.  which you can see on the image, draw with other color.   Now my question is other line points is not correct.  the correct value is should start at red line.

Comment: @Hunk, your description is still too confusing and you are not showing code. What do you mean by "Every line is channel"? When you say "this polygon" what polygon are you referring to? When you say "which you can see on the image" which of the (currently) four images are you referring to? When you say "the correct value is should start at red line" - which red line in which image are you referring to? Your final image (at present) has at least four red lines. If you mean that three of them don't start on the fourth that is true - but we need to see all relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this is locally projected to 2D?

Offsetting a line means you just add offset to its endpoints. The perpendicular shift is computed in 2D very simply. You have line endpoints `P0,P1` and want line `Q0,Q1` which is parallel to `P0,P1` at distance `l` so:

```cpp
dp = P1-P0                 // line direction vector
dp /= length(dp)           // make it unit
dq =  vec2( +dp.y, -dp.x ) // rotate by 90 deg in 2D so dq is perpendicular to dp
dq *= l                    // offset is now equal to size l
Q0 = P0 + dq
Q1 = P1 + dq
```

now if you are doing curves or polygons you have to handle the edges see:

- [draw outline for some connected lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068534/2521214)

if this is 3D then you have to use `cross` product to get the `dq` along with some reference direction (like normal to earth surface)

```
dq = cross (dp , some_refernce_direction_unit_vector)
dq *= l
```